XLOOKUP with flexible column for return_array and lookup_array



0
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J
K
L
M




1
Products

Shop

2023-S
2023-M

2024-S
2024-M






2












lookup_array


3
Product A

Shop3

80
2%

120
22%



2024-S


4
Product B

Shop1

320
17%

400
15%



return_array


5
Product B

Shop3

90
30%

750
8%

selected data

2024-M


6
Product B

Shop2

500
4%

70
4%

400

15%


7
Product C

Shop2

160
10%

245
10%

400

35%


8
Product D

Shop1

500
8%

130
4%

70

4%


9
Product D

Shop4

130
11%

130
4%

520

42%


10
Product E

Shop2

75
8%

650
15%

130

4%


11
Product E

Shop1

60
47%

90
7%

90

7%


12
Product E

Shop4

500
25%

400
35%

130

4%


13
Product E

Shop3

350
9%

140
13%

130

9%


14
Product F

Shop2

60
30%

130
9%

70

16%


15
Product G

Shop2

90
5%

370
12%






16
Product H

Shop1

390
27%

70
16%






17
Product H

Shop2

70
18%

520
42%








In Range M6:M14 I want to get the corresponding data based on the values in Range K6:14. 
However, I want to have the flexibility that  

the lookup_array is used based on the input in Cell M3 and 
the return_array is used based on the input in Cell M5. For example if I would switch from 2024-M to Product the corresponding products from Column A should be listed. 


With reference to the answer in this question I am looking for something like this:
=LET(
     _A, K6:K14,
     _B, >> flexible based on input in Cell M3 <<,
     _RollingA, MAP(_A,LAMBDA(α,COUNTIF(α:K6,α))),
     _RollingB, MAP(_B,LAMBDA(α,COUNTIF(α:H3,α))),
     XLOOKUP(_A&"|"&_RollingA,_B&"|"&_RollingB,XLOOKUP(M5,A1:I1,A3:I17)))


Note: 
Values in the lookup_array are not unique. In this example 130, 400 and 70. Therefore, in case the frequency of the values in Range K6:14 does not match with the frequency of the values in the return_array then in Range M6:M14 they should be matched to the values in Range K6:14 in a descending order. (The example formula above already handles it this way).

What formula do I need to make the outcome in Range M6:M14 work based on a flexible lookup_array and return_array?

The solution already lies in the answer posted by JvdV Sir,


• Formula used in cell M6
=LET(
     _A, K6:K14,
     _B, A1:I1,
     _C, A3:I17,
     _D, XLOOKUP(M3,_B,_C,""),
     MAP(_A,LAMBDA(α, @DROP(TOCOL(FILTER(IFS(_D=α,_C),N5=_B),3),
     COUNTIF(K6:α,α)-1))))


And this is using the existing formula in the context of the OP, with a slight modification:
=LET(
     _A, K6:K14,
     _B, A1:I1,
     _C, A3:I17,
     _D, XLOOKUP(M3,_B,_C,""),
     _RollingA, MAP(_A,LAMBDA(α,COUNTIF(α:K6,α))),
     _RollingD, MAP(_D,LAMBDA(α,LET(δ, INDEX(_D,1), SUM(N(δ:α=α))))),
     XLOOKUP(_A&"|"&_RollingA,_D&"|"&_RollingD,XLOOKUP(M5,_B,_C)))


Or, Bit similar as above, but shorter, and running custom LAMBDA()
=LET(
     _A, K6:K14,
     _B, A1:I1,
     _C, A3:I17,
     _D, XLOOKUP(M3,_B,_C,""),
     _Fx, LAMBDA(α,δ, MAP(α, LAMBDA(ε, SUM(N(δ:ε=ε))))),
     XLOOKUP(_A&"|"&_Fx(_A,K6),_D&"|"&_Fx(_D,INDEX(_D,1)),
     XLOOKUP(M5,_B,_C)))



Adopting from earlier answer:
=LAMBDA(k_, data_range, col_headers, header_for_lookup, header_for_return,
    LET(
        h_, INDEX(data_range, , XMATCH(header_for_lookup, col_headers)),
        i_, INDEX(data_range, , XMATCH(header_for_return, col_headers)),
        freq, LAMBDA(arr,
            LET(
                indices, SEQUENCE(ROWS(arr)),
                MAP(indices, LAMBDA(i, SUM(IF(TAKE(arr, i) = INDEX(arr, i, ), 1, 0))))
            )
        ),
        h_freq, h_ & " " & freq(h_),
        k_freq, k_ & " " & freq(k_),
        xlook, XLOOKUP(k_freq, h_freq, i_),
        formatted, IF(RIGHT(header_for_return, 2) = "-M", TEXT(xlook, "0%"), xlook),
        formatted
    )
)(K6:K14, A3:I17, A1:I1, M3, M5)

